# jquery mobile Mobipick - set min date to 4 days from today

Tags: jquery-mobile, datepicker

I recently found the mobipick calendar and I really like it due to its fast performance.
However I am having some trouble setting the minimum date four days from now.
If you go on the mobipick website, you can add min="..." in the html attribute, but it doesn't specify today's date.
The following code can be found on the website as well,
how can I achieve this?

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var picker = $("#picker", this);
    picker.mobipick();

    picker.bind("change", function () {
        var date = $(this).val();

        // formatted date                   
        var dateObject = $(this).mobipick("option", "date");
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="picker"  type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set the min date four days from now, create an input element

```
<input type="text" />
```

and add this JavaScript

```
$( selector ).mobipick({
    minDate: (new XDate()).addDays( 4 )
});
```

You need version 0.6 for this example to work, download or fork at GitHub https://github.com/sustainablepace/mobipick. I've also added a working example at http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/demo-advanced.html, see section "Datepicker with dynamic min date".

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Haha thanks. I'm the same guy that messaged you on twitter about the question.